# Has anyone developed a tool for checking app for Retina images?

Tags: ios, retina-display

Has anyone developed a tool to scan an iOS app directory to assure that all `.png` images have matching `@2x.png` images?  I could muck around for 2-3 hours and develop a Java app to do it.  However, while I'm not at all good with shell scripts, I figure it can probably be done in a few lines of shell script (and I'm happy to give one of you guys the opportunity to demonstrate your brilliance doing it :-)).

Comment: (Curious -- the question was quite specific, and it received a very good, useful answer.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick shell script. This even handles images with `~ipad` or `~iphone` suffixes.

```
#!/bin/bash

for img in `find . -name '*.png' | grep -v "@2x"`; do
    noext=${img%.png}
    suffix=
    base=${noext%~ipad}
    if [ "$base" != "$noext" ]; then
        suffix="~ipad"
    else
        base=${noext%~iphone}
        if [ "$base" != "$noext" ]; then
            suffix="~iphone"
        else
            base=${noext}
        fi
    fi
    retina="${base}@2x${suffix}.png"
    if [ ! -f $retina ]; then
        echo "Missing $retina"
    fi
done
```

Run this from the root of your project and it will check every image found.

I just found a problem with one of my images. I had the `@2` but no `x`.

Update: I just started playing with python. Here's the same script written in python:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import fnmatch
import os

for root, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('.'):
    for filename in fnmatch.filter(filenames, '*.png'):
        if filename.find('@2x') == -1:
            noext = filename[:-4]
            suffix = ''
            base = noext
            if noext.endswith('~ipad'):
                suffix = '~ipad'
                base = noext[:-5]
            elif noext.endswith('~iphone'):
                suffix = '~iphone'
                base = noext[:-6]

            retina = os.path.join(root, base + '@2x' + suffix + '.png')
            if not os.path.exists(retina) :
                print('Missing ' + retina)
```

Answer (score 0):

i've used [slender](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/slender/id493656257?mt=12) for that in the past